# Javascript Date Object incosistency in month numbering?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm confused about date in JS... As I know months are numbered 0-11, sa creating

```
var x = new Date(2014, 2, 1)
```

Will give me **1st of march**. But creating `var x = new Date(2014, 2, 0)` **gives February**, so x.getDate() will give me not the number of days in march, but in february... Should this rather return days of march if its number is 2 (with numeration from 0)?

Also is there a way to set monday as first day of the week in getDay() method?

Comment: As 1 is the first, 0 represents a day back into the previous month

Comment: `var x = new Date(2014, 2, 0)` and x returns `Fri Feb 28 2014 00:00:00` and therefore `x.getDate()` will return 28..  here 0 represents the last date of the previous month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Months Ranges from 0 to 11.0 being January wheres the day of month start with 1, so if you  use 0 in day it gives previous months last day.So in your case you should use

```
var x = new Date(2014, 1, 1) // for  1st feb 2014
```

You can change the start of week to `Monday` as follows

```
Date.prototype.mGetDay = function() {
  return (this.getDay() + 6) %7;
}
```

Refer this article for [details](http://javascript.about.com/library/blweekstart.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If you have already accepted months start with 0, this is not inconsistent, but it's a bit weird:

```
new Date(2014, 2, 1) //1st of March
new Date(2014, 2, 0) //28th of February
new Date(2014, 2, -3) //25th of February
new Date(2014, -2, -3) // 28th of October of 2013
```

So it takes the year, then adds the month (subtracting if negative) and then it does the same with the days

Answer (score 0):

It's not inconsistent. Months are represented using integer values, "beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December."

Also `getDate()' does not give you the number of days, but
"Returns the day of the month (1-31) for the specified date according to local time."

Please see [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global%5fObjects/Date)